# Apache camel is moving file into .done even if exception occurs

Tags: java, apache-camel

During the loading process of file, an exception occurs in orchestration database but apache camel still copied file into .done instead of .failed . Can someone provide code and flag in property file to move to .failed folder when that exception occurs

Comment: which component ftp or file

Comment: Do you have exception handler that sets handled to true? If so then camel will consider the transaction complete as the error was handled.

Comment: <doCatch>
<exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
<log message="COULD NOT PROCESS FILE.  ${exception}" />
<!-- set strategy file status failed??? -->
<bean ref="executionStatusQueries" method="failed" />
<to uri="direct:immediate-email-error" />
</doCatch>

Comment: Above is the current code written in do catch, Please help me with the code.
@erayy it is a file component